# How to integrate DynamicsCRM with botframework v4 using nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm, botframework

I am able to get the auth token from office 365. Using that auth token I have to integrate DynamicsCRM with botframework v4 and also use mysql to get the queries to be loaded into the function and execute.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific Botframework/DynamicsCRM adapters. However, your bot runs in Node, which means it can do anything you can do in JavaScript.

I recommend looking through [the JavaScript samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/samples) for how to make API calls to DynamicsCRM. Add that JavaScript code into your bot, as appropriate and then your bot will be integrated with Dynamics.